# Chunk array by value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, parent

how do you chunk array like this below?

```
array(
[0] => array(
    ['id'] => '1',
    ['parent_id'] => ''
)
[1] => array(
    ['id'] => '2',
    ['parent_id'] => ''
)
[2] => array(
    ['id'] => '3',
    ['parent_id'] => '1'
)
[3] => array(
    ['id'] => '3',
    ['parent_id'] => '1'
)
[4] => array(
    ['id'] => '3',
    ['parent_id'] => '2'
)
)
```

I'd like to group subelements (with specified parent_id) to do a separate foreach.

Comment: you have reconstruct your array by placing the sub elements under a tree of a parent_id it self

Comment: one option is to walk through the array with `foreach` and create a new array manually depending on the current sub-array values.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a simple foreach and rearrange the array.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $element) {
  $result[$element['parent_id']][] = $element;
}
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3ar-ixg